# How to get date and author using Beautiful Soup web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm creating a template for extracting news from websites for semantic analysis. I've just started learning to do web scraping with bs4 and selenium.

I could achieve to separate and get the title, subtitle, post id and text from each news.

```
title = soup.find_all('h1')[1].text
subtitle = soup.find_all('h2')[0].text
news_id  = (soup.find("article"))["id"]
text = article(corpus) >#function and argument defined earlier
```

I tought I achieved to extract the **date** but the function I used (`soup.find_all("span")[39].text` ) is not a good pattern for all news.

I need a function that works to extract date and author from the following:

```html
 <span class="author">
     Por <strong><span>Djenifer Dias</span></strong> <span>
       8 jun 2021, 12h15    </span>
 </span>,
 <span>Djenifer Dias</span>,
 <span>
       8 jun 2021, 12h15    </span>
```

I need to get the **author** "*Djenifer Dias*" and the **date** "*8 jun 2021, 12h15*".

Could someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Grab the span with the class `"author"`, then take the first and second child spans. Not difficult.

Comment: Is the structure of the "author" tags always the same? Including a link to the page/site might make it easier to get answers.

Answer (score 1):

To get author name and date from the HTML you can use following example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
 <span class="author">
     Por <strong><span>Djenifer Dias</span></strong> <span>
       8 jun 2021, 12h15    </span>
 </span>,
 <span>Djenifer Dias</span>,
 <span>
       8 jun 2021, 12h15    </span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

author = soup.find(class_="author").span.get_text(strip=True)
date = soup.find(class_="author").find_all("span")[-1].get_text(strip=True)

print(author)
print(date)
```

Prints:

```
Djenifer Dias
8 jun 2021, 12h15
```

---

Or using CSS selectors:

```py
author = soup.select_one(".author > strong").get_text(strip=True)
date = soup.select_one(".author > span").get_text(strip=True)
```